# Cannot load Rails application with gruff gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, gruff

I am trying to load a Ruby on Rails application that uses the [Gruff gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/gruff). I can load Gruff fine in `irb`, but whenever I try to load the app (via `ruby script/server`), it crashes. Here's the full stack trace:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:303:in `search': undefined method `empty?' for :gruff:Symbol (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:274:in `find_name'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:259:in `activate'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:67:in `gem'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/config/environment.rb:60
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `require'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:488:in `load'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:488:in `load'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:488:in `load'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:60
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `require'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `require'
    from /Users/mdippery/Projects/nees/ceespm/rails-server/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:39
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

How can I fix this so the app will run?

Comment: How are you trying to require it? Some code would assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the gem need to be installed directly into your rails app dir?

From [here](http://gruff.rubyforge.org/):

> Rails Plugin
>
> Gruff is easy to use with Rails.
>
> ```
> gem install gruff
> cd vendor/plugins && gem unpack gruff
> ```

If you've only done `gem install gruff` this might explain it not working in rails but working in irb.

Comment: This solved the problem. I also "thawed" Rails and re-froze it at 2.3.5 (it was a stale project that had been frozen at 1.2.5).